# What should a main game loop do?

Tags: architecture, game-loop

*Generally*, what are the core things that one should do in the game loop, and what are some things that one shouldn't do in the game loop?

Comment: **Note to future visitors**: although this was an interesting and relevant question when it was asked ~10 years ago when the site was shiny and new, this is not a good representation of the questions we expect today; it is on-topic but does not really present an issue to be solved.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

**The main game loop handles three major tasks:**

1. Get user input
2. Update the game state
3. Draw the game

**A simple game loop just mushes these three tasks into one while loop. This has some undesired results:**

1. Game runs at different speeds on different computers.
2. CPU (can be needlessly) pegged at 100% usage.
3. "Game states"/menus are missing or mixed with game code.
4. Main game loop is very long and hard to maintain.
5. Code is difficult to extend/port to other platforms.

**Advanced gamed loops address the issues listed above.** Here are some useful articles:

- [deWiTTERS Game Loop](https://dewitters.com/dewitters-gameloop/)
- [Integrating a timer into a game loop](https://web.archive.org/web/20141225174719/https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Timers#How_to_use_them.3F)
- [Managing Game States in C++](http://gamedevgeek.com/tutorials/managing-game-states-in-c/)
- [XNA Game State Management](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/samples/gamestatemanagement) and [Network Game State Management](http://creators.xna.com/en-us/sample/network_game_state_mgt_sample)
- [Understanding the Game Main Loop](http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2010/08/17/understanding-the-game-main-loop/)

**For an excellent example game loop, take a look at the Allegro skater demo game:**

- Game loop code is in [framework.c](https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/blob/28b2be2f8a8b941c7319af7fe77c3eec6995da09/demos/skater/src/framework.c#L238).
- Browse full source code [here](https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/tree/master/demos/skater).

Other related resources:

- Glenn Fiedler's article about robust framerate independence, "[Fix Your Timestep!](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/)"
- This deals with a number of different ways to write your game loop:
  [Multithreaded Game Engine Architectures](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/1830/multithreaded_game_engine_.php)
- [Game Loop · Sequencing Patterns · Game Programming Patterns](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html)

**Game loops often do the same type of work for most games, so I have been thinking of a way to make a generalized game framework.** It is better to write one implementation of a game loop and share it between games. It saves work when creating a new game, and improvements to the shared game loop can be shared by all games (for example, adding a FPS counter or screen capture feature).