# Free glut game loop

Tags: c++, game-loop

I'm trying to make a game with freeglut, but im still learning it and I don't fully understand what the looping does or whether I have to call it myself,

I've already read this article [A good way to build a game loop in OpenGL](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8623/a-good-way-to-build-a-game-loop-in-opengl) and didn't understand the answers

I get that glutmainloop() will call whatever I set in glutdisplayfunc() but I don't know how often or where I should put the game loop code

So my question is Where do I put the game loop code and how do I call it?

Comment: Spencer, did you see the link that was provided in your previously closed question about this? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8623/a-good-way-to-build-a-game-loop-in-opengl

Comment: Yes, that's the link I have posted in this post it doesn't really fully explain the glutmainloop and it's more about setting a timestep

Comment: @SpencerKillen: Of course it didn't fully explain the glutMainLoop; It specifically said *not to use GLUT*. That's your answer: Stop using FreeGLUT and switch to something else if you're making a game

Comment: if its so bad why are there so many tutorials for game dev using it?

Comment: because it's been around for quite some time, although that doesn't say anything about the quality or usablity