# How to make async step timing (game loop) using Box2D and C++

Tags: c++, box2d, websocket, timing

I'm making a game in C++ using Box2D and WebSocket++. The world needs to updated every `1/60 second`. Meanwhile the WebSocket server handles players. How I should make the interval? I know there's no `setInterval` function in C++, but I can do something like this:

• make async function - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234403/using-setinterval-in-c/33234557

• make async thread - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40915/simple-multithread-timer

or maybe there's a lib?

*Note: this isn't a duplicate of [How should I write a main game loop?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/651/tips-for-writing-the-main-game-loop) because here I need **asynchronous** game loop. In linked topic there are synchronous game loops.*

Why I won't use `while` (sync loop):

- commands after `while (loop)` are never excuted if `loop` is set to `true`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tips for writing the main game loop?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/651/tips-for-writing-the-main-game-loop)

Comment: @SethBattin I think no, because here I need **asynchronous** game loop (as another thread or async function).

Comment: Can you explain why it has to be asynchronous?  It's not obvious from your question.

Comment: @SethBattin Edited the question. Commands after `while (true)` are never excuted.

Comment: @SethBattin I'll read input for excuting another commands made by me, such as kicking players etc...

Comment: If you want to poll input from another thread, why can't you do it from inside the `while(true)`? What's going to come after the loop?

Comment: You don't need asynchronous game loop. You just need to call some part of code asynchronously/non-blocking.

Comment: @Mars Thanks, I didn't think about that! If you can please add your answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you fell into "I need this!" scheme. But all you need is just call some specific part of game loop asynchronously or non-blocking.

How to achieve this? Make sure whole loop is executed 60 times every second. In more proper words: Make sure every iteration takes less than 16.(6) ms. If it takes longer (your loop "lagged"), make two (or more) updates next frame, so the average FPS remains constant. In the loop gather user input, network data, update game state, render. With this, you can have another thread running WebSocket or a non-blocking function that checks whether anything is in network buffer to read. If not, it returns immediately.

Anything past the while loop is... not a game anymore. Make some cleanup there or anything you find appropriate. Loop might take some bool `isRunning` as condition and be handled inside.