# Game loop implementation

Tags: c++, game-loop

I'm implementing simple `Windows` game. Here is my game loop, which I've written based on some tutorials found on the Web:

```
constexpr nanoseconds ms_per_update(500ms);
TimePoint current_time;
TimePoint start_time = Clock::now();
nanoseconds delta_time;
nanoseconds lag(0ms);

while (continueRunning) {   

    while (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

        if (WM_QUIT == msg.message) {
            OutputDebugString(L"--- WM_QUIT (WndMain) ---\n");
            continueRunning = false;
        }
    }

    current_time = Clock::now();
    delta_time = duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(current_time - start_time);
    start_time = current_time;
    lag += delta_time;

    while (lag >= ms_per_update) {
        Game::Update();
        lag -= ms_per_update;
    }

    Game::Render();
}
```

Here are my questions

What really the `Update` and `Render` methods should do? Am i right that `Update` should for e.g. run through all game entities just updating theirs coordinates while the `Render` should call `Render` method for every game object which will just draw it on the screen having the position set by `Update`?

Comment: Welcome to [gamedev.se]! _"Am i right that [...]"_ Yes. There is not much of a question in this post, you answer your question yourself.

Comment: @Vaillancourt Ok, thx:-)

Comment: Check the [tag:game-loop] for more stuff on game loops, notably, [this one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/651/what-should-a-main-game-loop-do) has resurfaced lately.

Comment: @Vaillancourt Ok, Thx again:-)