# Is there a clear distinction between Game Loop and Gameplay Loop?

Tags: game-design, terminology

I'm wondering if Game Loop and Gameplay Loop are equal tho I feel like Game Loop has a larger scope than Gameplay Loop, or Gameplay Loop is called Game Loop for short. Anyone knows the origin of the two game-design concepts?

Answer (score 4):

The term "game loop" usually refers to [the programming pattern](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/651/what-should-a-main-game-loop-do) that is the core of most game engines, while the term "gameplay loop" is a game design concept about how game and player interact. However, in a pure game design context, you sometimes have people say "game loop" when they actually mean "gameplay loop". So when you are talking specifically about game design and not about the implementation, the two terms are synonymous.

If you want to differentiate between gameplay loops at different scales of the design, then it is common to refer to them as "inner gameplay loops" and "outer gameplay loops". For example, when you design a 4X game like civilization, then you might describe an inner gameplay loop of picking units and moving units, while having an outer gameplay loop describing the turn progression (move units -> manage cities -> click next turn -> watch opponent actions -> read event messages). Or in an MMORPG you might have an inner gameplay loop of "pick enemy -> kill enemy -> collect loot" while you have an outer gameplay loop of "talk to questgiver -> go to quest location -> kill enemies -> return to questgiver".

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you! I had the question bc as a game designer I just started to learn game development and got to know the programming pattern "Start()...Update()...". So, I feel like there should be a clear distinction between the two terms, but you know people with different backgrounds tend to misuse the terms in their working context.

Comment: And then there are engines like Unity where `Start()` and `Update()` are default methods that are always executed at the same step in the cycle.

Comment: @Zibelas Yes, many game engines hide [their internal game loop](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) from the game programmers and instead expose APIs like that for injecting logic into it. But what does that have to do with the answer?

Comment: That was in direct response to OP about the statement programming pattern and the different background parts. From the different background the same word could have a different meaning rather than just a misuse of it.